# Large CSV will generate zero byte output

Tags: csv, elixir

I'm running the following code to read a CSV, process and write the output back to a CSV. My goal is to read a large file (26k lines, many rows and 13mb). 
When I run the sample data of 40 or 500 lines my output is ok.
But when I run on the entire data, my output is a zero byte file.

I'm using Elixir (`version 1.4`) on a Mac(10.11.6).

Now for the code:

```
# mix.exs

defp deps do
  [{:nimble_csv, "~> 0.1.0"},
  {:flow, "~> 0.11"}]
end
```

And:

```
# csv.ex

defmodule Csv do

  NimbleCSV.define(MyParser, separator: ",", escape: "\"")

  def run(file) do

    {headers, output} = config_data()

    file
    |> File.stream!
    |> MyParser.parse_stream
    |> Flow.from_enumerable
    |> Flow.map( fn x -> Enum.zip(headers, x) end)
    |> Flow.map(&each_line(&1))
    |> MyParser.dump_to_stream
    |> Enum.into(output)

  end

  defp config_data() do
    [headers | _]  = File.read!("headers.csv")
    |> MyParser.parse_string(headers: false)

    output = File.stream!("output.csv")

    {headers, output}
  end

  defp each_line(line) do
    line
    |> Enum.filter_map(&item_filter(&1), &item_map(&1))
  end

  defp item_filter({"Grand Total", _count}), do: false
  defp item_filter({_exam, count}) do
    if(count == "", do: false, else: true)
  end

  defp item_map({"client", count}), do: count
  defp item_map({exam, _count}), do: exam
end
```

Comment: Do you get all the data printed to console if you do `|> Enum.into([]) |> IO.puts` instead of `|> Enum.into(output)` and run it on the whole file?

Comment: @Dogbert it does output to console on the larger sample (500 lines), but I have no luck with the full source.

Comment: There is no output for the "full source"? Maybe everything is getting filtered out in the `filter_map`?

Comment: How exactly are you invoking the module and running the program? Could it be the case that the VM shuts down before the output can be written in case of the large input file, but there is just enough time to finish processing the smaller input file?

Comment: The filter only happens within each line as I want to remove each blank cell and collapse it to the left. What I'll try is to `Stream.take(500)` from the full source and see if it outputs.

Comment: @PatrickOscity I'm running `iex -S mix run` and then typing in the command `Csv.run("source.csv")`

Comment: @RobertoTrevisan you should be fine then. The described problem occurs only when you're doing long-running work outside the main process and not explicitly waiting for it to finish. Does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: I've tried moving from Lazy to Eager but still no luck.

Comment: It is an error on the file. There is some odd character. I just don't know how to find it.

Comment: If you can upload the whole code and file and the code to test it somewhere (Github?), I'll have a look.

Comment: Thanks @Dogbert the problem seems to be in the source file. It contains non-english characters, and in another attempt it complained about those characters and later about some displaced `"`.
Problem it was falling silently. I'll narrow down the exact lines that were filling and let you know.